# Make List<String> from value in query snapshot Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I'm new to flutter and I want to make two different Lists using only one function. I want one list to contain all the data (routes) but I want the second to contain only one value from the snapshot (locations).

```
getRoutes() async {
    final data = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection("Routes")
          .orderBy("driver")
          .get();
      List routeList = List();
      for(int i = 0; i < data.docs.length; i++) {
        routeList.add(data.docs[i]);
      }
      routes = routeList;
    locations = data.docs.map((element) => element["locationName"]).toString().toList();
    print(locations);
      setState(() {});
    }
```

I got the first list to come up right but when I try to make the location list, it shows up with every letter separated by a comma:

```
[(, O, n, t, a, r, i, o, ,,  , B, u, f, o, r, d, )]
```

It's probably pretty simple but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. How do I make each value show up as a regular string?

Comment: Try: `locations = data.docs.map((element) => element["locationName"]).toList();` or `locations = data.docs.map((element) => element["locationName"].toString()).toList();`

Comment: That's what I've already tried as you can see in my current code.

Comment: No, it is not the same. Please see where the parenthesis are. :)

Answer (score 1):

The element on the .map function is a DocumentSnapshot. You could define another

`final map2 = element.data()` and then get the
`map2["locationName"]`.
I would do:

```
   List<String> locations = [];
   data.docs.forEach((element) {
   final map2 = element.data();
   locations.add(map2['locationName']);});
```